# Pandas does not replace NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following the following table with several lines:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'Copy Interactions Report.xlsx')
```

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01235 | NaN | Louise | Spain |
| 01258 | NaN | Federica | France |
| 01365 | NaN | Martin | Portugal |
| 01355 | NaN | Valeria | Portugal |

My idea was to replace ColumnB with values in ColumnD, however it does not seem like Pandas recognises the NaN values as empty cells. Just wanted to check what values Pandas think this column is filled with the following code:

```
for x in df['ColumnB'].values:
    if x == None:
        print('1')
    elif x == 'NaN':
        print('2')
    elif x == "":
        print('3')
    elif x == " NaN":
        print('4')
    elif x == "NaN ":
        print('5')
    elif x == "nan":
        print('6')
    elif x == "0":
        print('7')
```

But this doesn't work... so what's happening here?

Comment: what was the output? Also you dont check for NaN, you check if the string "NaN" is written in the column. To check if it is non a number (NaN) you can use functions shown here [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)

Comment: `df['B'] = df['D']`? or for NaNs only `df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(df['D'])`?

Comment: Why do you expect that you can modify data by printing values? Also, note that there's a difference between `"NaN"` (a string) and `NaN` (a special float that represents "not a number"). A cell containing the string `"NaN"` will not be considered empty by `pandas`.

Comment: I didn't get any output @Finn.

@/mozway can't do that because I first need to check another column. The issue here is that for now I can't find the empty values.

@/jfaccioni I am not trying to replace values by simply printing, I was trying to understand what Pandas think those cells values are and none of those print statement have produced any output.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal (updated) example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ColumnA" : ['01235' ,'01238'],
                   "ColumnB" : [np.nan, "foobar"],
                   "ColumnC" : ["Louise", "Federica"],
                  })

print(df)
```

results in:

```
    ColumnA  ColumnB   ColumnC
0   01235     NaN    Louise
1   01238  foobar  Federica
```

Now

```
nan_indices = df["ColumnB"].isna()
print(nan_indices)
```

gives

```
0     True
1    False
Name: ColumnB, dtype: bool
```

so we can do

```
df["ColumnB"][nan_indices] = df["ColumnC"][nan_indices]
print(df)
```

which results in

```
    ColumnA  ColumnB   ColumnC
0   01235  Louise    Louise
1   01238  foobar  Federica
```

Comment: I only want to fill ColumnB if this is empty. ColumnB is not fully empty unfortunately. So hence I needed to check the Pandas think those empty values are, so I can't use df["ColumnB"] = df["ColumnC"]

Comment: Thanks @cknoll. But it's still not working. I tried something like this: `for x, y in zip(df['ColumnB'].values, df['ColumnC'].values):
    if df["ColumnB"].isna():
        df['ColumnB'].values = y`. But this is not producing any change...

Comment: I think the intended way to tackle this problem is not a `for`-loop but using an boolean array (or pandas data series) as *mask*. This is what my answer does (mask is named `nan_indices`). However I recognized that my last edit was incomplete. I fixed it. Now my example data contains 1 NaN-entry (≙ empty cell in columnB) and one `"foobar"` entry in that column.

If it still does not work, can you edit your question such that it contains a minimal example data set where the problem occurs?

(A `for`-loop might work but is "unpythonic" and probably slower).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your "NaN" values are not exactly `NaN`. Let me explain. Let's take a look to this (modified) sample input:

```
ColumnA     ColumnB     ColumnC     ColumnD
01235   NaN     Louise  Spain
01258   NaN     Federica    France
01365   Italy   Martin  Portugal
01355   NaN     Valeria     Portugal
```

So, we'll have a "NaN" in the first row (0) and second column (1):

```
>>> reference_value = df.iloc[0, 1]
>>> print(reference_value)
NaN
```

Everything seems normal. But:

```
>>> print(type(reference_value))
<classs 'str'>
>>> print(len(reference_value))
4
```

Instead of a string of length 3, we have a length 4 string. This is because your "NaN" values are actually `"NaN "` (notice the space character at the end). With this information, and this variable, we can just replace the values we want using `.loc`:

```
>>> df.loc[df["ColumnB"] == reference_value, "ColumnB"] = df.loc[df["ColumnB"] == reference_value, "ColumnD"]
>>> df
   ColumnA   ColumnB    ColumnC   ColumnD
0     1235     Spain    Louise      Spain
1     1258    France  Federica     France
2     1365     Italy    Martin   Portugal
3     1355  Portugal   Valeria   Portugal
```

This reads "take the column 'columnB' of every row where the value in 'ColumnB' is equal to our reference value and replace that location with the value in 'columnD' of that same row".